# Route Not Passing Parameter to View in Laravel

Tags: php, view, laravel, controller

I have some problem to send parameter from route to view.

The logic:

1. signup form (firstname, lastname, email) (here is the code)

   ```
   public function postCreate(){
       $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), User::$rules);
       if($validator -> passes()){
           //validate function 
           $user = new User;
           $user->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
           $user->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
           $user->email = Input::get('email');
           $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
           $user->level = '1';
           $user->save();

           return Redirect::to('wizard/'. $user->email)->with('message','Terima kasih telah melakukan registrasi, ' . $user->firstname);

       } else {
   ...
   ```
2. send the parameter email using the route (here is the code)

   ```
   Route::get('wizard/{emailid}', array('before' => 'signup', function($emailid) {
    $email['emailid'] = $emailid;
    if (isset($email)) {
       //dd($email);
        return View::make('console.wizard')->with('email_id', $email);
    } else {
        return View::make('signup');
    }
   }));
   ```
3. consume the email variable to view

i don't have any ideas how this works, i have tried `{{ Session::get('email_id') }}`, `<?php echo $email; ?>`

how to consume the email variable from route to view (blade=> wizard.blade.php) properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `$emailid` will always exist with this route.  If you had `wizard/{emailid?}`, then `$emailid` may be null.  In this case, you would want to check `if(!empty($emailid)) {} else {}` instead of `isset($emailid)`.  The first parameter of `->with()` is how you access the variable in your blade.

---

*route.php*

```
Route::get('wizard/{emailid}', array('before' => 'signup', function($email_id) {
    return View::make('console.wizard')->with('email_id', $email_id);
}));
```

*console.wizard.blade.php*

```
Email: {{$email_id}}
```

---

`GET /wizard/testing` should output `Email: testing` (as long as everything with the before filter `signup` works).

Comment: the view is throwing error `ErrorException
Use of undefined constant email_id - assumed`

Comment: Ah sorry, its been a while since I worked in Blade: `{{$email_id}}`

Comment: okay it's worked. One more question, if i want to passed the data using the stored procedure, is there any method to use eloquent? can u suggest some good tutorial to begin with?

Comment: The [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) docs are actually pretty solid.  You should be able to use the `$email_id` to find a `User` model, and then pass the object to the view.  Then you can execute any PHP in Blade, like: `{{$User->getName()}}` (assuming you passed it like `->with('User', User::find($email_id))`).